# How to write matrix cell piece inequality rigorously?

Tags: recursion

Let $\alpha = 0.05$. Let p-value $n \times n$ matrix B. 
Set zero all values which are less than $\alpha$.

\begin{equation}
B_{k}(i,j) = 
\begin{cases}
0 \text{ if } B_{k}(i,j) \geq \alpha \\
1 \text{ otherwise}
\end{cases}
\label{eq:cell}
\end{equation}

Is this right?

Comment: Let alpha be zero. Contradiction...matrix value larger than zero would have now two values:0 and 1.

Comment: @hhh Alpha is now defined first. No contraindication should come.

Comment: No recursively wanted, add some dagger or upper Script to differentiate  the two matrices